# Django building nested formsets

Tags: django, django-forms, formset

I'm trying to get my head around how to create a nested formsets in Django. I notice there are several other questions around nested formsets, but I can't seem to figure out how to apply it all to my case (I'm quite new to Django).

I've been looking at the example here: http://yergler.net/blog/2009/09/27/nested-formsets-with-django/ - although I'm using Django 1.3 and apparently this example needs some tweaking to work with 1.3. The other slight difference I have is that in my model, rather than having a 1-many relationship between the block-building (or quiz-question in my case), I have a  many to many relationship (since I may, in the future, but not now, want to allow the same question to be in multiple quizzes) - but I don;t think this is the cause of my current error.

So far I have:

forms.py:

```
ResponseFormset = inlineformset_factory(Question, Response, extra=4) 

class BaseQuestionFormSet(BaseFormSet):
    def add_fields(self, form, index):
        super(BaseQuestionFormSet, self).add_fields(form, index)
        # created the nested formset
        try:
            instance = self.get_queryset()[index]
            pk_value = instance.pk
        except IndexError:
            instance=None
            pk_value = hash(form.prefix)

        # store the formset in the .nested property
        form.nested = [
            ResponseFormset(data=self.data,
                            instance = instance,
                            prefix = 'RESPONSES_%s' % pk_value)]

class QuizForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Quiz
        fields = ('title', 'description')
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(),     
            'description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 3}),
        }


class QuestionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('title', 'type')
        widgets = {     
            'title': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 3}),
        }


class ResponseForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Response
        fields = ('title', 'score')
        widgets = {     
            'title': forms.TextInput(),
            'score': forms.DecimalField,
        }
```

and then in views.py:

```
def create_quiz(request):
    QuestionFormSet = formset_factory(QuestionForm,extra=5,formset=BaseQuestionFormSet)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        quiz_form = QuizForm(request.POST)
        question_formset = forms.QuestionFormSet(request.POST,)

        if quiz_form.is_valid():
            quiz = quiz_form.save(commit=False)
            quiz.owner = request.user
            quiz.save()

            #if question_formset.is_valid():
                # do something here 

            #return HttpResponseRedirect('saved/')
    else:
        quiz_form = QuizForm() # An unbound form
        question_formset = QuestionFormSet()

    return render(request, 'mquiz/quiz.html', {'quiz_form': quiz_form,'question_formset':question_formset})
```

The error that I get is:

```
'QuestionFormFormSet' object has no attribute 'get_queryset'
```

The example is obviously for editing an existing block object, but for now I'm just looking to create new quiz/questions (so using an empty form - will come back to editing it once I have the creation working) - so guessing that that's partly the issue?  Also I think I'm getting mixed up as my Question has no instance=Quiz (in the Yergler example, each Building has an instance=Block).

Any help or pointers very much appreciated!
Alex